# What are smart ways to preview/embed files in html page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file, dropbox, box-api

In my app (Rails), users can refer to files (mostly docs, pdfs, ppts, and images) hosted on Box.com. I wanted to embed the files so they can be previewed in my app, without users having to be redirected to Box.

Unfortunately it seems the Box API does not provide the embed method anymore (Box API V1 `get_embed_code` method used to return an embed code to show the file in Flash). So at this point, if I continue using Box, I can only let users download the file or redirect them to the shared link of the file, which is not really acceptable for my use case.

How can I achieve the behavior I am looking for, using Box or other services?

Answer (score 1):

For image files, you can get thumbnails up to 256x256 : http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-get-a-thumbnail-for-a-file

For office documents, it is correct that we don't have preview for those available in V2 yet. I've used [Crocodoc](http://crocodoc.com) before for generating HTML5 previews of Office documents and have been very satisfied.